# How to use Multi-Inputs in NetGraph with NetTrain?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I want to train a network,the first input is a `Integer`,the second input is `10-dims vector`.

Assume we have those data：

```
INPUTNOTE = 500;
Labels = RandomReal[1, {INPUTNOTE, 43}];
data = Transpose[{Join[List /@ Range[INPUTNOTE], RandomReal[1, {INPUTNOTE, 10}],2], Labels}];
generator = Function[<|"EmbeddingLayerInput" -> #[[1, 1]], "Input2" -> #[[1, 2 ;;]], "OutPut" -> #[[2]]|> & /@ RandomSample[data, #BatchSize]];
generator[<|"BatchSize" -> 3|>]
```

[image]

```
net = NetGraph[{EmbeddingLayer[128, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", Range[INPUTNOTE]}]], 
 CatenateLayer[], 512, Ramp, 43},
{NetPort["EmbeddingLayerInput"] -> 1 -> 2, NetPort["Input2"] -> 2, 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}]
```

[image]

```
NetTrain[net, generator]
```

> $Failed

But I see the doc of `NetTrain` has this description:

[image]

So What's wrong?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two small mistakes: First, if I run your code, I see this message in the message window:

> NetTrain::nfspec: Cannot train net: "Input" port of layer 2 is not fully specified.

So you need to specify the size of the `Input2` output port:

```
net = NetGraph[..., "Input2" -> 10]
```

When I run this, I get the message:

> NetTrain::invgenout: Output of generator function (<<1>>&)/@RandomSample[<<2>>]& was incorrect: **generator did not return an association or list of rules.**

(emphasis mine). So the generator is supposed to return an association of lists, not a list of associations:

```
generator = Function[
   Module[{samples = RandomSample[data, #BatchSize]},
    <|"EmbeddingLayerInput" -> samples[[All, 1, 1]], 
     "Input2" -> samples[[All, 1, 2 ;;]], 
     "Output" -> samples[[All, 2]]|>]];
```

With these changes, `NetTrain` runs fine.

(I ran into exactly the same problem the first time I used a generator function. IMO an example in the documentation would have been helpful)

Comment: Your response is soooo fast! Thank you!!!  It solve my problem