# generator didn't return a correct type in NetGraph with Multi-port

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In this example,`generator[<|"BatchSize" -> 4|>]` get an association of lists, but `NetTrain[net, generator]` can't be used.

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];
encoder1 = NetChain[{FlattenLayer[], 128, 8}, 
            "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"}]];
encoder2 = NetChain[{8}, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", Range[0, 9], "UnitVector"}]];

decoder = NetChain[{128, 28*28, ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}, "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Image", ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"}]];

net = NetGraph[{encoder1, encoder2, ThreadingLayer[#1*(1 - #2) &], 
                ThreadingLayer[#1*#2 &], ThreadingLayer[Plus], 
                decoder, ReplicateLayer[8], FlattenLayer[]}, 
                {NetPort["image"] -> 1 -> 3, NetPort["digit"] -> 2 -> 4, 
                NetPort["switch"] -> 7 -> 8 -> {3, 4} -> 5 -> 6 -> NetPort["Output"]}, "switch" -> 1]
```

[image]

This net can predict the image although it haven't be trained

```
NetInitialize[net][<|"image" -> trainingData[[1, 1]], 
                     "digit" -> trainingData[[1, 2]], 
                     "switch" -> 0|>]
```

[image]

generator also works well

```
generator = 
  Function[Block[{data = RandomSample[trainingData, #BatchSize]}, <|
    "image" -> data[[All, 1]], "digit" -> data[[All, 2]], 
    "switch" -> RandomInteger[1, #BatchSize], 
    "Output" -> data[[All, 1]]|>]];

generator[<|"BatchSize" -> 4|>]
```

[image]

But when type `NetTrain[net, generator]`,it throws error.

[image]

weird!What's wrong?

Comment: @nikie But in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145780/15961, you say  "the generator is supposed to return an association of lists, not a list of associations"

Comment: Good point, I can never remember which it is...

Comment: I think `ThreadingLayer` needs two inputs with the same dimensions. So you'll need to pass a tensor for the input `switch`

Comment: @it is the same dimension actually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get much better error messages if you pass a list of samples instead of a generator to `NetTrain`:

```
NetTrain[net, generator[<|"BatchSize" -> 10|>]]
```

> NetTrain::invindim: Data provided to port "switch" should be a list of length-1 vectors.

This is much more helpful, and if we change the generator so it creates a list of length-1 vectors for `switch`:

```
generator = 
  Function[Block[{data = RandomSample[trainingData, #BatchSize]}, <|
     "image" -> data[[All, 1]], "digit" -> data[[All, 2]], 
     "switch" -> ({#} & /@ RandomInteger[1, #BatchSize]), 
     "Output" -> data[[All, 1]]|>]];
```

Training with the generator works, too:

```
NetTrain[net, generator]
```

Comment: This way looks interesting,use `generator[<|"BatchSize" -> 10|>]` as param,then solve the problem.you are so expert